# User defined values aren't honored in program at later points

Tags: c, arrays, user-input

In the code below, the user is supposed to be able to define what nurses won't be available for work that week. The user has a list of the names, and they are supposed to type a number that corresponds to the name. Once that value is stored into the `slackers[4]` array, it should be using those user supplied values to remove those nurses from being selected come making selections. It doesn't seem to be honoring those selected values, despite `avail_nurses[9]` having the correct values at any point in time (I tested using `printf` statements).

Everything seems to be in good shape except that essential piece of the puzzle. I would appreciate some constructive critique and useful suggestions. If you can avoid it, don't write the code for me--I gotta learn somehow. Thanks in advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *names[] = { "Denise", "Inja", "Jane", "Karen", "Maggie", "Margaret", "MJ", "Queen", "Sherri",  NULL }; //ptr for names, 9 nurses
/*0 = Denise, 1 = Inja, 2 = Jane, 3 = Karen, 4 = Maggie, 5 = Margaret, 6 = MJ, 7 = Queen, 8 = Sherri*/
const char days[5][10] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
int randomNurse();
#define total_nurses 9 //number of nurses on staff
#define days_in_week 5 //number of work days in a week


int main() {

srand(time(NULL));
int day, pos, rand_num, i, j;
int slackers[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //array that holds the selections for who isn't working
int avail_nurses[total_nurses] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; //holds the status of each nurse, 0 = unavailable, 1 = available

/*this allows the user to repeat the program easily! flag determines if we run the program multiple times*/
while (char flag = 'y') {

    /*prints names */
    int temp_counter = 1; //counter
    char **name_ptr = names;
    while (*name_ptr) {
        printf("%i) %s\n", temp_counter, *name_ptr);
        name_ptr++;
        temp_counter++;
    }

    /*this assumes that no more than FOUR nurses will be away on any given week*/
    printf("\nEnter numbers that correspond to the nurses who won't be available for the week.\nType up to four numbers, each separated by a space.\n");
    printf("When you are done, press \"Enter\".\n");
    printf("If less than four nurses will be on leave, type a \"0\" in place of a selection.\n");
    printf("Example: 1 2 5 0\n\n\n");

    /*week selection of unavailable nurses*/
    do {
        printf("Who won't be here?  ");
    } while (scanf("%i %i %i %i", &slackers[0], &slackers[1], &slackers[2], &slackers[3]) != 4);

    /*checks the selections made, and sets the available nurses to the correct value, zero if they are slacking||vacationing*/
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
        int slacker = slackers[n];
        if (slacker >= 1 && slacker <= 9)
            avail_nurses[slacker - 1] = -1;
    }


    /*-----WEEKLY_ASSIGNMENT-----*/
    int pos_per_day[days_in_week] = { 5, 9, 9, 8, 5 }; //number of nurses needed each day
    int selection[days_in_week][total_nurses]; //the selected nurses per day 

    for (i = 0; i < days_in_week; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < total_nurses; j++) {
            selection[i][j] = -1; //initialize to -1 which means no nurse is selected
        }
    }

    //fill all the days of week 
    for (day = 0; day < days_in_week; day++) {
        for (pos = 0; pos < pos_per_day[day]; pos++) { //for every position needed that day
            do {
                rand_num = randomNurse();
            } while (!avail_nurses[rand_num]); //looks for available nurses (phrasing)
            avail_nurses[rand_num] = 0;  //change nurses status to not available
            selection[day][pos] = rand_num;  //fill the output array with appropriate nurse
        }
        for (i = 0; i < total_nurses; i++) {
            avail_nurses[i] = 1; //initialize the nurses status for next day use
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) { //make sure we shame the slackers...
            int slacker = slackers[n];
            if (slacker >= 1 && slacker <= 9)
                avail_nurses[slacker - 1] = -1;
        }

        /*DEBUGGING PRINTFs
        printf("\n\nSELECTION:\n");
        for (int x = 0; x < days_in_week; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < total_nurses; y++) {
                printf("%i\t", selection[x][y]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }*/
    }
    printf("\n");

    /*-----PRINTS SCHEDULE FOR WEEK-----*/
    for (i = 0; i < days_in_week; i++) {
        printf("%-10s: ", days[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < total_nurses; j++) {
            if (selection[i][j] != -1)
                printf("%-10s ", names[selection[i][j]]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fflush(stdin);

    /*asks user if they want the program to run again*/
    printf("\n\nDo you want to run the program again? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%c", &flag);
    if (flag == 'n' || flag == 'N') {
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\n\n");
        continue;
    }
}
return 0;
}

/*function to generate random nurse*/
int randomNurse() {

return rand() % 9; //random number 0-8, to pick nurse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `avail_nurses` array uses the value `1` to indicate a nurse that's available, the value `0` to indicate a nurse that's not available as that nurse has already been assigned, and `-1` to indicate a nurse that's not available because that nurse is a slacker. You then test whether or not a nurse is available with `!avail_nurses[rand_num]`. This statement is true if `avail_nurses[rand_num]` is `0` and is false if it's any other value. The means when `avail_nurses[rand_num]` is `-1` it will exit the loop just like it does when it's `1`.

To fix this bug either change the test to `avail_nurses[rand_num] <= 0` or use only `0` to indicate unavailable nurses regardless of the reason why.